# "error: #error "OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11 support"

Tags: opencv, makefile, phpize

How can I fix this?

I installed OpenCV 4.1.0 without a problem on Centos 7.6 following this guide:

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-centos-7/

Now I'm trying to install php-opencv

https://github.com/hihozhou/php-opencv

And it's failing when I `make`.  (Under the **Compile and install php-opencv extension** header on that link).

Many thanks, COMPLETELY out of my depth here.

Comment: The problem seems to arise proximally from the OpenCV 4 headers.  Are the OpenCV 2.4.5 packages available as part of the CentOS 7 distribution insufficient for your needs?

Comment: If you *must* use OpenCV 4, then the problem appears to be that g++ 4.8 needs a command-line option to provide (partial) support for C++11.  By default, it supports (most of) C++98, plus some extensions.  You *may* be able to resolve this by rerunning `configure` and specifying the C++ compiler with needed option: `./configure CXX='g++ -std=gnu++11'`.  Do not omit the quotes.

Comment: I'm away from my computer at the moment but I'll certainly try this tomorrow, thank you